# Cant call method of custom ConstraintLayout class?

Tags: java, android-layout

I want to make a custom ConstraintLayout so I can trigger some functions from the activity where its initialized.

I have the following code:

First initialized my custom view in layout:

```
<package.com.app.Main.LavadasView
        android:id="@+id/main_autolavados_lavadas_lavadas_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
...
        />
```

This is my custom class LavadasView, constraint layout initialized from another XML file:

Java class

```
public class LavadasView extends ConstraintLayout {


    public LavadasView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);
//Inflate view from XML layout file
        LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.lavadas_view, this);



    }

    public void resetView(){
        //Some ui updates
    }

}
```

LavadasView xml file, just a normal constraint layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And in my Activity I get the instance with `findViewById`mehtod, then I want to call the resetView function and that gives me a null pointer exception related to LavadasView:

```
LavadasView lavadasView = (LavadasView) findViewById(R.id.main_autolavados_lavadas_lavadas_view);

//Call this method later on
        lavadasView.resetView();
```

SO what am I doing wrong? I've looked up and thats the correct way to get layout instance isnt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the constructor of your `LavadasView`. When your `Activity` is inflated it will call the `LavadasView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` constructor on you custom layout. In this constructor you need to call the `super(context, attrs)` for the `ConstraintLayout` to be properly inflated, but you're only calling `super(context)` which is why you get the `NullPointerException`.